# How to get time to retrieve data in Monogdb

Tags: javascript, performance, mongodb, mongoose

When I execute `db.mycollection.find()` query, how can I get to know the time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
db.collection.find().explain('executionStats')
```

See, if that helps.

For more info refer [Analyze Query Performance](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/analyze-query-plan/)

Comment: I can see "executionTimeMillis" : 0 field, but its showing 0 may be due to less data?

Comment: Yes, I have a collection which has more then 800 documents, and when I execute explain command, I get "executionTimeMillis" : 158, So it depend upon no of documents you have, and Once you implement index/compound index (as per your need) your execution time will decrease.